# iOS background bluetooth on phone startup

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm developing an iPhone app that the user can wake up with a Bluetooth LE peripheral.  It uses the `bluetooth-central` UI background mode, and this seems to be working well.

The following code works great when the app is launched by the user tapping an icon:

```
// called from AppDelegate’s didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
// following call will result in callback to centralManagerDidUpdateState
myCentral=[[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

...

//CBCentralManager delegate methods

-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    NSLog(@"centralManagerDidUpdateState called");
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        // error handling
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"scanning for peripherals");
        //following call will result in callback to centralManager didDiscoverPeripheral ...
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
        [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[DESIRED_SERVICE_UUID] options:options];
    }
}
```

However, I don't want the user to have to tap an icon.  I want the app to spring to life in the background, and be summoned to the foreground by the BTLE peripheral.  I used the VoIP background mode to launch my app in the background, and it does in fact launch into the background mode.  However, `centralManagerDidUpdateState:` is never called until the user brings the app to the foreground.

**How can I activate background bluetooth functionality on startup?**

I am using iOS 8.1, but I believe this applies to iOS 7 as well.

Comment: Have you set up bluetooth state preservation and restoration? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW10

Comment: Ah, I see - it's entirely possible that the myCentral object is getting lost.  I'll look into that.